# Calculation of collector current for T1

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, open-collector

I have a two-transistor circuit which has two voltage sources to operate. T3 is just there to connect and disconnect its path base current path.

I tried solving via nodal analysis but I am not getting very accurate results. Is there any other method by which it can be solved?

I think I am confused with base and emitter current calculation at both T1 and T2. What would be the base and emitter current formula if I have T1's base (V.T1_Base) node voltage ?

[image]

Comment: What value at which node are you expecting to get?

Comment: Please draw your circuits left-to-right to make it readable. Reading your right-to-left schematic diagram is as hard as playing music from a mirror-image musical score.

Comment: What is T3? Is it a switch? If so, how is it connected?

Comment: What is to the left of L1, off screen?